Problema Con Validaciones de EditForm en un Bucle en Blazor
Tengo un una tabla HTML, en donde quiero aplicar validaciones del modelo de datos. (Mi articuloDTO) busco los artículos, los traigo a la tabla, y allí al salir del articulo, si la validación no es correcta, valida, hasta allí no tengo problema.
Dentro de la tabla, tengo un botón, que al tocarlo ejecuta una acción. Pero al tocar ese botón, aunque este configurado como Submmit, no valida que la información este correcta.
Alguien sabe como se debe hacer la validación de los datos en un EditForm de blazor? dejo algo de código. Quiero evitar hacerlo manualmente, pero por ahora no encontré solución.
    <EditForm Model="@articulo">
     <DataAnnotationsValidator />
     <ValidationSummary />
     <table class="table table-sm table-hover" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 95%; max-height: 200px ">

         <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th style="width: 37px;">Cod.</th>
                 <th style="width: 100px;">Descripción</th>
                 <th style="width: 40px;">Lista</th>                 
                 <th style="width: 25px;">D1</th>                
                 <th style="width: 55px;">Precio</th>                
                 <th style="width: 35px;">Agregar</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             @foreach (ArticulosCotizacionDTO art in articulos)
             {
                 <tr>
                     @if (art.PrecioVenta == 0) { art.PrecioVenta = art.PrecioLista; }

                     <td>@art.Codigo</td>

                     <td style="width: 200px;">@art.Descripcion</td>

                     <td>@art.PrecioLista</td>

                   
                     <td>
                         <InputNumber id="Dt1@Ind" @bind-Value="art.Dt1" style="width: 100%" @onblur="()=>EjecutarCalculos(art)"> </InputNumber>
                         <label></label>
                         <ValidationMessage For="@(() => art.Dt1)" />
                     </td>
                     
                     <td>@art.PrecioVenta</td>
                     <td>
                         <button href="cotizar_cliente" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" @onclick="()=> SelectArticulo(art)">Agregar</button>

                     </td>


                 </tr>
                 
             }
         </tbody>
     </table>
 </EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<ArticulosCotizacionDTO> OnSelectArticulo { get; set; }
    private string texto;
    private ICollection<ArticulosCotizacionDTO> articulos { get; set; }
    private ArticulosCotizacionDTO articulo = new ArticulosCotizacionDTO();
    private bool loadArticulos = false;
    private string ArticuloSeleccionado { get; set; }
    private int Ind { get; set; }

 private async Task SelectArticulo(ArticulosCotizacionDTO artSeleccionado)
 {
  

     ArticuloSeleccionado = $"{artSeleccionado.Descripcion}  {artSeleccionado.PrecioVenta.ToString()}";
     await OnSelectArticulo.InvokeAsync(artSeleccionado);

 }

